# Фокус элемента в ListView

Tags: wpf, c#

В приложении имеется ListView (и ItemTemplate для его элементов) для отображения списка подключений. Хотелось бы отключить фокус для элементов ListView либо скрыть отображение фокуса.

Подскажите, как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то отключение фокуса - нарушение accessibility. Но если очень хочется, то попробуйте сделать их не-focusable, выставив свойство [Focusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) в False.